# Data Download Without loading data on front end

Tags: c#, html, datatable

I am looking for something which can help my data to download on click of button without loading my data on front end as it contains huge data, which is causing data loading speed issue.

Comment: Paging, perhaps?

Comment: Build a console program to generate the files at backend. You can use the button the trigger or run the console program.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Ajax to bring data in small quantities, and with the Paging you can go showing them:

> https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp